# How to use contextual filters to a View for use as a sort criteria?

Tags: views

I want a View with a default sort criteria that can be overridden by a contextual filter.  For example, the URL might end like this: `?sort=popular`.  `popular` would be associated with one field and `recent`, the default, would be associated with another field.
This is on Drupal 7 and Views 3.

Comment: htoip.  I changed the term arguments to contextual filters, the new name for arguments in D7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use "exposed filters", they will use url name/value pairs similar to contextual filters.
If you don't want to show the exposed filter to the visitor you can hide them.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how this translates to Drupal 7 and Views 3, but I have done the following with Drupal 6 and Views 2 using [hook_views_query_alter](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21views%21docs%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7)

```
function mymodule_views_query_alter (&$view, &$query)
{
    if ($_GET["sort"]) {
        $sort = check_plain(trim(strtolower($_GET["sort"])));

        switch ($sort) {
            case "title":
                $query->orderby = array("node.title ASC");
                break;
            case "order":
                $query->orderby = array("node.nid DESC");
                break;
            case "somefield":
                $query->orderby = array("node_data_field_somefield_field_somefield_value ASC");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The trick is to make the views w/ the sorts, and look at the SQL, and use this to update your code.

Comment: Looks like a good answer, but it's a little over my head.  I'll have to come back after I've learned some more.

Comment: @htoip Were you able to confirm or deny this?

Comment: @Jeff I don't think I ever implemented that solution, but I am now familiar with all its parts and it looks like it would work perfectly.  Usually that's not how anyone should want to handle arguments, but I had to maintain compatibility with old URL's.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, query will look in following way:

```
$query->orderby[] = array('field' =>'node_title', 'direction' => 'DESC');
```